# Backgroundworker is freezing my GUI

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I have a WPF application that validates a user. When that user is successfully authenticated, the interface changes and says hello to the user. I want that Welcome message to appear during 5 seconds and then change it with another content. This is my Welcome message that launches the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
LabelInsertCard.Content = Cultures.Resources.ATMRegisterOK + " " + user.Name;
ImageResult.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
ImageResult.SetResourceReference(Image.SourceProperty, "Ok");
BackgroundWorker userRegisterOk = new BackgroundWorker
   {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
        WorkerReportsProgress = true
   };
userRegisterOk.DoWork += userRegisterOk_DoWork;
userRegisterOk.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And this is my `BackgroundWorker` with the five seconds delay:

```
void userRegisterOk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != uiCurrent)
        {
            uiCurrent.Post(delegate { userRegisterOk_DoWork(sender, e); }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            ImageResult.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            RotatoryCube.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LabelInsertCard.Content = Cultures.Resources.InsertCard;
        }
    }
```

But the Backgroundworker freezes my GUI for the five seconds. Obviously, what I want to do is launch the code inside the worker 5 seconds after the Welcome message.

Why is it freezing the GUI?

Comment: What do you think `uiCurrent.Post` is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you intended:

```
void userRegisterOk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != uiCurrent)
    {
        // Wait here - on the background thread
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        uiCurrent.Post(delegate { userRegisterOk_DoWork(sender, e); }, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // This part is on the GUI thread!!
        ImageResult.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        RotatoryCube.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        LabelInsertCard.Content = Cultures.Resources.InsertCard;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly! I need the uiCurrent because if not, another thread (main one) owns it, and I can't modify them. But with this I solved it! Thanks a lot! 
PS: when I'm allowed, I will post your answer as the good one.

Answer (score 4):

You're explicitly defeating the purpose of the background worker.

Your code switches back to the UI thread in the callback and does everything there.